# Is Qt3D a part of Qt5?

Tags: qt, qt5, qt3d

I have installed Qt5 libraries in windows but there is no document about Qt3D in Qt assistant.
Is Qt3D a part of Qt5 or it has been removed from release version 5?

Comment: Just want to make update: According to this thread ( http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/26020 ), Qt3D should be added in Qt 5.2 (by end of 2013 year).

Comment: [An update for your update](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/09/30/qt-5-2-alpha-available/#comment-1191741). The schedule has slipped and Qt3D will not make it into 5.2.

Comment: Further update: does not appear to have made it into Qt 5.3 either.

Comment: Further further update: it's [coming back](http://www.kdab.com/category/blogs/qt3d/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer & comments were correct at the time, but the situation has now changed.

[As of Qt5.5](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.5), Qt3D is now included as a "technology preview" (I interpret this phrase as an indication that it's not deployment-ready, so there could be some bugs and the API could change).

It's very important to note that the Qt3D that was available for previous versions of Qt has been Qt3D 1.0, while the version included with Qt5.5 is v2.0, which has been developed by a different software team and **has a very different API**.

More info from the new developers [available here](http://www.kdab.com/qt3d-technology-preview-released-qt-5-5-0/).

Note also that Qt3D v1.0 was never actually included 'properly' with Qt in any version, though was (apparently) reasonably easy to build along with Qt if checked out from git from v5.0 through 5.4.

Answer (score 16):

Yes. Qt 3D became a standard Qt library in the [Qt 5.7 release](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/06/16/qt-5-7-released/).

> With Qt 5.7, we are bringing in the Qt 3D module. This module has been
>   available as a Technology Preview for two releases now, and I’m happy
>   to announce that it has now reached the state where it is becoming a
>   fully supported member of the Qt family!

This addition was a long time coming. Roughly 4.5 years ago, [they announced they were dropping it from the Qt 5.0 release](http://www.mail-archive.com/interest@qt-project.org/msg04398.html). Since then, it's undergone significant rework. Now, seven minor versions later, it's finally made it back in.

Comment: How to install QtQuick3D? There is a chain of deprecated repositories pointing to each other. After cloning `git://gitorious.org/qt/quick3d.git` I found only a README that this one is also deprecated and now Qt(Quick)3D is built as a submodule of Qt5. This requires a custom Qt5 build. Do you know of a better method?

Comment: Speaking as a Qt5 fanboi to Digia; wouldn't you say it is important to put that somewhere "official"? For example on the download page for Qt5? Or on the frontpage of the Qt3D git page. Or both. Just my two cents!